Esau’s so called blessing sounds like a curse. Is it really considered a blessing?
Genesis 27
38 Esau pleaded, “But do you have only one blessing? Oh my father, bless me, too!” Then Esau broke down and wept.
39 Finally, his father, Isaac, said to him,
“You will live away from the richness of the earth,
and away from the dew of the heaven above.
40 You will live by your sword,
and you will serve your brother.
But when you decide to break free,
you will shake his yoke from your neck.”
The “blessing” Esau’s father gave him was terrible. Would it really be considered a blessing?

In my reading, this is not a curse, but rather a prophecy or even an intelligent prediction of the inevitable consequences for Esau, given that Jacob has been already blessed and thus designated as the God's chosen. However, that Esau will be able to shake this yoke is genuinely a blessing.

One can ask the question if a birth right is a ticket to heaven, or if an other criteria would be in play then? Because, the suffering poor Lazarus in the Gospel story doesn't seem to have been particularly blessed.

@Constantthin I think in the case of Jacob and Esau the birthright is inheriting the covenant with YHWH - becoming a father of the great nation in the promised land, alongside Abraham and Isaac. (In my knowledge no heavenly rewards had been promised at that point.) Why not all the descendants of Isaac would be made a part of this nation's covenant is open to discussion.

@Roger V. Exactly a prophesy, not a “blessing”. So correct.

@Roger V. So in other words you are saying that if we get to heaven one day it is possible that Esau might be there too?

@Constantthin I only point out that interpreting the text (as it was intended by its authors) and reinterpreting it from the Christian viewpoint are not the same thing. The latter probably belongs to the Christianity community: Jews, Christians, Muslims, Atheists, and others might have different view on whether Esau will go to heaven.

I would call it a mixed blessing. Why? Because it conveys both challenges and a form of empowerment.
While this blessing acknowledges Esau’s difficult future, it still carries weight as a formal pronouncement over his life.
It recognizes the hardships Esau will face, living in less fertile lands and experiencing conflict but it also contains a promise. A promise of eventual freedom (“you shall break his yoke from your neck”).
In biblical times, a father’s blessing was a significant and solemn event. Even a blessing that predicts struggle can be considered a legitimate blessing. It provides guidance, sets expectations, and can influence the course of events.

The true blessing was perhaps the change of Esau's heart.
A few points to first consider: [1]

Isaac’s plan to bless Esau went against God’s prophecy that “the
older shall serve the younger,” indicating an attempt to subvert
divine will (Genesis 25:23; Romans 9:12).
Esau’s sale of his birthright for a meal showed contempt for his
inheritance, and Isaac’s knowledge of this could imply an attempt to
bestow a blessing that Esau had already traded away (Genesis
25:29-34; 27:36).
Esau’s marriages to Hittite women, which were a source of grief to
Isaac and Rebekah, suggested that he was not aligned with the
family’s covenantal values (Genesis 26:34-35).
Isaac was aware of Esau’s violent nature, which would typically
disqualify him from receiving such a significant blessing (Genesis
25:28).
Jacob was described as a mild or "complete" man, which could imply
that he was more fitting to receive the blessing (Genesis 25:27).
Isaac did not seek God’s guidance through prayer before deciding to
bless Esau, treating the blessing as a personal prerogative rather
than a spiritual mandate.
Isaac kept his intention to bless Esau secret, possibly because he
knew Rebekah would oppose it due to the prophecy she received from
God (Genesis 25:28).

According to Rashi's Commentary:

Esau replied, “Behold, I am going to die”: (The birthright is something unstable, for the [sacrificial] service will not always be
the function of the firstborn, for the tribe of Levi will take it.
Furthermore,) said Esau [to Jacob], “What is the nature of this
service?” He replied, “There are many prohibitions and punishments and
death penalties involved with it, as we learned (Sanh. 83a): ‘These
are the ones who are liable to death: Those [performing the Temple
service] who have imbibed wine and those who have not cut their
hair.’” He (Esau) said, “Behold, I am going to die because of it
(i.e., the birthright); if so, why should I want it?”


and Esau despised: Scripture attests to his wickedness, that he
despised the service of the Omnipresent.

Perhaps, (several commentaries indicate) by selling his birthright, Esau gave up his claim to the material and spiritual privileges that came with it, which included the right to the patriarchal blessing.

It was the height of wickedness for Esau to suppose that with the “sale” of his birthright he did not also convey the patriarchal blessing that went with it.  (Coffman's Commentaries on the Bible)


In giving away the birthright he had given away his right to the blessing of his father as the covenant head. But Esau had worked
against that anyway. (Coffman's Commentaries on the Bible)


Esau selling his birthright indicated his lack of respect for the
position and privilege in which he obtained. His careless treatment
of his God-given blessing shows his true focus was on temporary
desires over a lifetime blessing. (biblestudytools)


Nowhere in Esau do you see repentance. This is seen in the fact that
he demands that his father give him a blessing apart from Jacob's.
Here we see worldly desires in Esau and a worldly remorse in Esau, but
we do not see spiritual repentance. (Dr. Ligon Duncan)


...And that is if God loves you, He's not going to let you get away with sin without disciplining you, because He doesn't want to see you destroyed by sin. And sin will destroy you, despite how it advertises
itself... (Dr. Ligon Duncan)

Is it a blessing that perhaps God needed to discipline Esau because He loved him? (The Lord disciplines the one He loves)

It's true that it sounds more like a curse. However, Esau did indeed lead a blessed life:

a. Behold, your dwelling shall be of the fatness of the earth: These words of Isaac sound more like a curse than a blessing. Yet, in fact, Esau ended up being a blessed man. Many years later when he met Jacob
again, he could say the blessed words I have enough, my brother
(Genesis 33:9). (Enduring Word)

Coffman's Commentaries on the Bible says:

The blessing of Esau did allow one small hope, that, on occasions,
Edom would be able to throw off the yoke of Israel. “An example of
this was in the reign of Joram, king of Judah (2 Kings 8:20-22; 2
Chronicles 21:8-10).”(F22) Another occasion is mentioned in the Book
of Obadiah (Obadiah 1:10). Still another, perhaps, is seen in the fact
that Herod the Great was descended from Esau; and he was ruling Israel
ruthlessly in the days of Christ.

Let us not forget that Jacob himself would bow down to Esau. Genesis 33:1,3

Now Jacob lifted his eyes and looked, and there, Esau was coming, and
with him were four hundred men. So he divided the children among
Leah, Rachel, and the two maidservants... Then he crossed over before
them and bowed himself to the ground seven times, until he came near
to his brother.

Again, the true blessing was perhaps the change of Esau's heart. Where even knowing that he would live a tough life that he was able to say:

But Esau said, “I have enough, my brother; keep what you have for
yourself.” (Genesis 33:9)


According to the Jewish Virtual Library.
The oath was as binding as a written document.

First a starving Esau took an oath whereby he agreed to relinquish
his birthright to his brother in exchange for a meal (25:29–34). The
oath, it should be noted, was as binding as a written document. The
narrative at this point contrasts with pentateuchal law, which
guarantees certain privileges to the firstborn (Deut. 21:15–17), and
reflects an earlier state of affairs in which the transfer of the
birthright was possible.


Thank you for your eloquent response. I have a follow up question to it; what are Esau’s sins? Are you referring to him giving up his birthright? We are to view it as a sin rather than a flat out d**b decision?

@Lyd I've added an edit: It was the height of wickedness for Esau to suppose that with the “sale” of his birthright he did not also convey the patriarchal blessing that went with it. (Coffman's Commentaries on the Bible)
In giving away the birthright he had given away his right to the blessing of his father as the covenant head. But Esau had worked against that anyway. He doesn't even realize he's been in a fight against God for God had said that Jacob would be blessed.

Great! Thank you!

Esau clearly sold his birthright under a duress, when he didn't have any food and was at the point of starving. Punishing him for this "sin" is a bit harsh. It is also not clear why the birthright is negotiable at all. And if such a sale was legal - what's the point of all the ruse against Isaac?

@RogerV. I take it as being dramatic rather than under duress. I mean, Esau sells his birthright for bread and lentil soup. It’s described that Esau came from the field but there is no indication that he had no other means to obtain food. Even after eating, scripture says that "Esau despised his birthright." He despised his God given right.

More precisely: "Esau came from the field tired/famished/exhausted and hungry" (depending on translation).

@RogerV. Oh, I don’t doubt that Esau was hungry or tired. However, the narrative suggests that Esau made a conscious choice to prioritize his immediate physical needs over his birthright, which is portrayed as a moment of weakness and shortsightedness. To me, the phrase “I am about to die; of what use is a birthright to me?” indicates a dramatic rather expression of his current state rather than an actual life-or-death situation.

@RogerV. My idea of duress was: Duress is a compulsion, coercion, or pressure to do something. In a legal sense, this refers to forcing someone to do something, or to sign a contract, by threatening his personal safety, his reputation, or other personal issue. (https://legaldictionary.net/duress/). I was thinking of it more as Jacob forcing Esau. Perhaps Esau's hunger could be considered duress? To me, it does not appear to be the result of external threats or coercion by Jacob, but rather a voluntary exchange, albeit under the pressure of Esau's own physical needs.

a dramatic rather expression of his current state rather than an actual life-or-death situation - this is your own claim, which suits your conclusions, but not what the text says.

@RogerV. I do not mean to sound aggressive if I may have. Esau saying, “Look, I am about to die; what good is the birthright to me?” This could be read as an expression of extreme hunger, but it doesn’t necessarily confirm that Esau was literally on the verge of death. The text does not provide additional details about his physical state beyond Esau's own words. Esau’s statement as dramatic would be consistent with his impulsiveness (he planned to kill Jacob) and disregard for the birthright that characterized his actions. (He also disregarded family values by marrying two women from Canaan)

@Jason sounds plausible to me. Thanks for taking my doubts seriously.
